# Why my bash terminal shows "?[30;43m" instead of a well formatted text when using Symfony CLI commands like server:start?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, phpstorm

I switched from Windows cmd terminal to bash in PhpStorm and now when I run Symfony CLI commands like `server:start` it shows characters like **?[30;43m** instead of a formatted text.

I tried these Symfony commands on both PhpStorm and Visual studio code with the same results. It did work on git bash terminal though.

Here a screenshot from PhpStorm executing `server:start`:

[image]

and a screenshot using Windows cmd for the same command:

[image]

Do you know how to solve this problem?

### My solution

**I left Windows to Linux**. Now everything works fine. I could not make it work properly on Windows though.

I think the `?` means that my terminal on windows had trouble with the escape character used to interpret the formatting code `[30;43m`.

Here is my homemade explanation of this kind of formatting code:

> Use `echo -e` to use text formatting.

Syntaxe:

```sh
\e[FORMAT;FORMAT;FORMATm
```

- `\e` is the escape character (`\033` works too).
- `[` mark the beginning of the format code.
- `;` separate formating code sequence.
- `m` mark the end of the format code.
- `FORMAT` has to be replaced by a formatting code:

  - character effects using 1 digit:

    code | effect
    ---- | ------
    0    | normal
    1    | bold
    4    | underlined
    5    | blinking
    7    | reverse colors
  - colors using 2 digit:

    - first digit (the target):

      code | effect
      ---- | ------
      3    | foreground
      4    | background
    - second digit (the color):

      code | effect
      ---- | ------
      0    | black
      1    | red
      2    | green
      3    | brown
      4    | blue
      5    | purple
      6    | cyan
      7    | light gray

Comment: update: the same problem appears with my git bash terminal when using `php bin/console make:entity`

Answer (score 0):

These are color codes, from the ANSI Escape codes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Some terminals use these codes to apply text formatting, while others just display them as regular text. Most programs that print such codes in an attempt to color their output also have an option to silence them, in order to make the display more readable on dumber terminals.

Comment: Ok, and do you know how to silence them or make them work properly?

Comment: I've never touched any PHP stuff so far, so I'm not familiar with your dev tools. You'll find that in the manuals.